quick way to find sub-vector of a cpp vector
Say I have a 4 dimensional C++ std::vector, x. In the numpy's notation, I can easily get access to a sub-vector y=x[:, :, :, 2] using slicing. In cpp, is there a fast way to do this?
A naive way is of course to using 3 for loops with the last dimension fixed to 2 in x. Not sure if there's a better way to handle this senario. And also, is a general solution for this kind of problems in C++, i.e. for an Nd C++ vector, fix arbitrary m number of axes and decay the vector to (N-m)d?

C++ doesn't have 4-dimensional vectors; it has vectors of vectors of vectors of vectors.  That's going to complicate your life a bit.

c++'s std vectors are limited to 1d. I would recommend looking into other libraries which offer multidimensional arrays. I can suggest investigating Eigen::Tensor, and Kokkos::View as some examples, but I'm sure there are many others.

"A naive way is to using 3 for loops with the last dimension fixed to 2".   Presumably, numpy does something like that under the covers, for the example you have provided.
